# Select rows based on variable column name

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

This does not seem difficult, but I am stacked here.
I want to reference table column by variable name for filtering and cannot understand why this is not working.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
    [VarColumn = "Val",  Phone = "123-4567"],
    [VarColumn = "Val2",  Phone = "987-6543"],
    [VarColumn = "NA",  Phone = "543-7890"],
    [VarColumn = "OTHER",  Phone = "543-7890"]
    }),

    VariableColumn = "VarColumn",
    filter = Table.SelectRows(Source, each (Table.Column(Source, VariableColumn) = "OTHER"))
in
    filter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    filter = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Record.Field(_, VariableColumn) = "OTHER")
```